# How to make BaseAdapter work

Tags: android, baseadapter

I'm trying to make category listview . I want use my code easy to understand and using

I have a MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
ListView lst;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lst = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstView);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("Sameer Blog " + i);
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Ahmad " + i);
        }
    }
    lst.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

}

and a MyCustomAdapter class like this

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    // save separator position
    mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}


public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView txtView = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
                txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
                break;
        }

    }
    txtView.setText(mData.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

But I always get NullPointerException in logcat . Somebody can hep me ????

Comment: Post your logcat and mark the line in which the error occurs

Comment: what line do you get a null pointer ??

Comment: Override notifyDataSetChanged() in your MyCustomAdapter class...And call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); when you add data into listitem.

Comment: I think this line mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 2):

May be it is due to

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you call in `addItem` and `addSeparatorItem` without setting adapter in listview.

Try changing your:

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

to:

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    mInflater =LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
}
```

Comment: No , I don't think so . I use ListActivity , it work fine . But when I change to Activity. It make error

Comment: @NamNguyen can you please post your logcat with error messages